# Unable to load gem after its installation

Tags: ruby, rubygems, addressable-gem

How to use an external library in Ruby?

I just installed [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) library as stated in the documentation and write the following code:

```
require 'addressable/uri'
```

and it still says:

> E:/software/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- addressable/uri (LoadError)

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems to not find your installed gem. Did you install it under the same ruby version? Is addressable listed in the output of command 'gem list' ?

Comment: Is it a Rails app? Or really what I'm asking is, does your app use bundler? All Rails apps do.  Other apps can. Do you have a `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 0):

You need install addressable. Run the following in your command line:

```
$ gem install addressable
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try uninstall all versions of addressable, and then reinstall it.